# How to clone a android open source project to my desktop

Tags: android, git, github

Essentially I am trying to clone this android open source project to my desktop.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/android-4.3_r1

I am not sure what exactly to do.

I have tried:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/android-4.3_r1
```

But I got the error:

```
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
```

So how would I have to create a repository and clone it in there?

I am just completely unsure on how to do this locally in my desktop.

Comment: The url you are trying to clone is a commit that has been taged not a whole repo. try `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock`

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me :

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/`

This would download the entire repository.
Then you can checkout any branch you want.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to clone the base repo:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/
```

Dive into the directory it just created:

```
cd DeskClock/
```

Then you will need to checkout that tag you want to start from

```
git checkout tags/android-4.3_r1
```

Answer (score 1):

First, verify the Git Repository URL you use is correct, as given in the official [Git repositories on android](https://android.googlesource.com/)

In Android Studio, Go for **File > New > Project from Version Control > Git**.

Paste the Git Repository URL (Don't include `git clone` here, **only the URL**)

Click on **Test** to verify

This should work, as it did for me. This procedure is simple and straightforward.